# Como faço para colocar o eixo Y invertido (decrescente) no R?

Tags: r, lattice

Estou tentando apresentar uns gráficos sobre coeficiente de uniformidade,
porém normalmente neste tipo de gráfico, o eixo Y fica organizado em ordem decrescente, de 100 a 0.

Gostaria de saber como faço para realizar este procedimento. Pode ser para a função `plot` e/ou para a função `xyplot` do pacote Lattice.

```
cuc <- c(11.37,11.38,11.44,11.47,11.29,11.10,
11.29,11.40,11.45,11.35,10.53,10.39,
10.12,10.25,10.04,9.93,9.92,9.97,
10.91,9.29,8.67,9.40,10.14,11.36,
10.44,9.62,9.68,10.41,11.22,11.43,
10.12,9.81,7.28,10.45,11.16,11.16,
10.39,10.70,11.40,11.44,11.23,10.71,
11.52,11.36,11.43,11.49,11.27,11.38,
11.55,11.84,11.40,11.42,11.25,11.41)

foot <- length(cuc)

X <- seq(((1/foot)*100)/2,100,(100/foot))

plot(cuc~X, type="l", lwd=2)

require(lattice)

xyplot(cuc~X, type="l", lwd=2,col=1)
```

Exemplo do gráfico

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simples, inverta a resposta e depois customize os eixos!

Exemplos com seus dados:

```
## Dados
cuc <- c(11.37, 11.38, 11.44, 11.47, 11.29, 11.1, 11.29, 11.4,
         11.45, 11.35, 10.53, 10.39, 10.12, 10.25, 10.04, 9.93,
         9.92, 9.97, 10.91, 9.29, 8.67, 9.4, 10.14, 11.36,
         10.44, 9.62, 9.68, 10.41, 11.22, 11.43, 10.12, 9.81,
         7.28, 10.45, 11.16, 11.16, 10.39, 10.7, 11.4, 11.44,
         11.23, 10.71, 11.52, 11.36, 11.43, 11.49, 11.27, 11.38,
         11.55, 11.84, 11.4, 11.42, 11.25, 11.41)
foot <- length(cuc)
X <- seq(((1/foot) * 100)/2, 100, (100/foot))
##-------------------------------------------

## Com graphics
plot(-cuc ~ X, type = "l", lwd = 2, axes = FALSE)
axis(3)
axis(2, at = -pretty(cuc), labels = pretty(cuc))

## Com lattice
library(lattice)
xyplot(-cuc ~ X, type = c("l", "g"),
       lwd = 2, col = 1,
       scales = list(
           x = list(alternating = 2),
           y = list(at = -pretty(cuc), labels = pretty(cuc)))
       )

## Com plotrix
library(plotrix)
revaxis(x = X, y = cuc, type = "l")
```

Answer (score 5):

Basta inverter a ordem do argumento `ylim` dentro do comando `plot`. Normalmente, ele faz o eixo ir do mínimo ao máximo da variável resposta. No teu caso, faça o `ylim` variar do máximo ao mínimo.

```
cuc <- c(11.37,11.38,11.44,11.47,11.29,11.10,
         11.29,11.40,11.45,11.35,10.53,10.39,
         10.12,10.25,10.04,9.93,9.92,9.97,
         10.91,9.29,8.67,9.40,10.14,11.36,
         10.44,9.62,9.68,10.41,11.22,11.43,
         10.12,9.81,7.28,10.45,11.16,11.16,
         10.39,10.70,11.40,11.44,11.23,10.71,
         11.52,11.36,11.43,11.49,11.27,11.38,
         11.55,11.84,11.40,11.42,11.25,11.41)

foot <- length(cuc)

X <- seq(((1/foot)*100)/2,100,(100/foot))

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(cuc~X, type="l", lwd=2, main="Eixo Tradicional")
plot(cuc~X, type="l", lwd=2, ylim=c(max(cuc), min(cuc)), main="Eixo Invertido")
```

[image: Resultado do exemplo]